# Google analytics filter suggestion?

Tags: google-analytics

I have an ASP.NET MVC 2 app that uses URLS such as:

```
/rsvp/33c4cf68-a2fe-4c0f-9834-08838e0532c3
/rsvp/4f28dad7-b05c-4887-818f-b4ae664b7192
/rsvp/bf9b6595-171b-4f8b-821e-2d1df22440e5
/rsvp/7b5ae33a-2e79-43fc-92fb-05800c640610
/rsvp/5d56bce6-aa62-4b41-80c4-aa1dd1d2c192
```

where each user has their own GUID.

Is it possible for me to use a filter of some sort in Google Analytics to roll all these up under simply

```
/rsvp/
```

??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just apply a search and replace filter that looks something like this:
[image]